# Find largest score word

Tags: go, struct

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type word struct {
    str   string
    score int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Enter a string of words: ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    str, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    strin := strings.Trim(str, "\n")
    high_word := get_word(strin)
    fmt.Println(high_word)
}
func get_word(in string) []word {
    rune_word := strings.Split(in, " ")
    stru_sl := make([]word, len(rune_word))
    for i := 0; i < len(rune_word); i++ {
        stru_sl[i] = word{str: rune_word[i], score: (get_score(rune_word[i]))}
    }
    return stru_sl
}
func get_score(in_w string) int {
    var num int
    score_map := make(map[string]int)
    alpha := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    alpha_run := strings.Split(alpha, "")
    for i, a := range alpha_run {
        score_map[a] = i + 1
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(in_w); i++ {
        if m, ok := score_map[string(in_w[i])]; ok {
            num += m
        }
    }
    return num
}
```

I've got the code above that gives me a list of structs corresponding to the words you put in, and its score calculated by adding up positions of each letter in the alphabet (1-26). My next step here is to find the word with the highest score. I can do the swap method and sort the structs, but what's the smartest way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking for a better way to find the score or sort based on score ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find only the word with the highest score of course sorting isn't necessary, you can scan linearly and update what is highest on every step.

something like that:

```golang
highestScoreWord = words[0];
for i := 1; i < len(words); i++ {
    if words[i].score > highestScoreWord.score {
        highestScoreWord = words[i];
    }
}

return highestScoreWord;
```